# repeating form fields a user defined number of times

Tags: html, forms, element

I am working on a web based form that needs to have the flexibility to add as many entries as the user needs. This means that a chunk of my form needs to be able to repeat it's self an undefined number of times it might be 1 or 2 or it could be 50. Is there a method of dynamically repeating form elements?

Comment: Are you using any sort of framework?  Angular?  React?  Or just raw html and javascript?

Comment: Please provide more details regarding your question. It will be easier for others to help you. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance

Answer (score 1):

For completion, here is a pure JS solution:

You can create a JavaScript variable which contains the HTML text for the elements you want to create:

```
var formHtml = "<input type='text' name='inp'>"
```

And then you can insert the `formHtml` variable to the end of a DOM element called `yourId` by:

```
document.getElementById("yourId").innerHTML += formHtml;
```

Update:  JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zjd3g0cy/

Answer (score 0):

You can append input field to the form using

```
$('.selector').append("<input type='text' name="xyz[]" />");
```

Comment: It's not even mentioned that author needs jQuery. -1 for jQuery in 2017.